# Upgrade issue from Debian Server Squeeze 6 to Wheezy 7 - still on kernel 2.6

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, debian-wheezy, upgrade

I upgraded from Debian Squeeze 6 to Wheezy 7 but it seems i am using the old kernel.

```
# uname -r
2.6.32-042stab072.10
```

But i have the newer kernel installed

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
linux-image-2.6-amd64                           install
linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64                       install
linux-image-amd64                               install
```

What should i do?

Here is the proccess i followed to upgrade:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove

reboot

echo '' > /etc/apt/sources.list

cat <<EOF >> /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
EOF


apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade

reboot

apt-get install linux-image-2.6-amd64

reboot
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on an OpenVZ (container) based virtual machine. As a result you have no control over the kernel; it is provided by your hosting provider, and you are limited to whatever the provider chooses to provide.

If you want a different kernel, you either need to contact your hosting provider, or use something other than OpenVZ.